# Different notations for attributes and properties of UML classes

Tags: properties, attributes, language-lawyer, uml, class-diagram

UML defines a ***property*** to be either an ***attribute*** of a classifier, or the member end of an association, or both at the same time. At the same time, an *attribute* is a *property* that is owned by a classifier. So the line between the two is very thin.   For a class, the usual notation for an attribute is to appear in the attribute compartment of the class:

[image]

But The UML 2.5.1 specification allow a graphical notation as well (chapter 9.5.4, page 114):

> In a Classifier, an attribute may also be shown using association notation, where only an **aggregation adornment** (hollow or filled diamond) may be shown at the tail of the arrow.

Shall we understand this clause as meaning, that the association notation for an *attribute* requires the aggregation notation as follows?

[image]

If yes, wouldn't this be confused with an aggregated property? And wouldn't this contradict UML 2.5.1 when it says that there is no semantic for shared aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the sentence tries to define, what can be shown on an *association like* notation for an attribute. This applies to attributes, that are *not* at the same time association ends. In absence of an association, there can be no information about the opposite end. Therefore, only adornments that belong to the attribute itself can be shown. Since the aggregation kind is a property of the attribute, it can be shown.

Comment: Interesting semantic analysis. So it's not "[MAY-ONLY](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/517999/373969)" aka "MUST",  but it's just "[MAY](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119#section-5)" i.e. optional,  and the ONLY applies to what the option could be.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I could use shared aggregation, composite aggregation or "none" aggregation on one side,  and multiplicity and role name on the other, because all these adornments belong to the attribute.  But I couldn't use navigability nor dot notation, nor qualifier, nor association name, nor opposite role since these would imply an association. Did I get it right?

Comment: Navigability in the direction of the attribute's type is implied, so that will be allowed. Note, that your quote from the UML spec mentions an "arrow". Ownership is also implied by being an attribute, so I would say the dot notation is allowed as well.